# Set extra host in environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose to run my application. And for do that I need to set the hosts inside container (it's depends on the environment i'm running).

My approach was:

Create an environment file and set the variable:

```
#application.env
SERVER_IP=10.10.9.134
```

My docker compose file looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:

  api:
    container_name: myApplication
    env_file:
      - application.env
    build: ./myApplication/
    entrypoint: ./docker/api-startup.sh
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - redis    
    extra_hosts: &extra_hosts
      myip: $SERVER_IP
```

But my problem is that the variable SERVER_IP is never replaced.

When I run docker-compose config I see:

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: /...../myApplication
    container_name: myApplication
    depends_on:
    - redis
    entrypoint: ./docker/api-startup.sh
    environment:
      SERVER_IP: 10.10.9.134
    extra_hosts:
      myip: ''
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

I've tried to replace the variable reference using $SERVER_IP or ${SERVER_IP} but it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a file `.env`, added single line `HOST=test.example.com`, then did this in docker-compose:

```
extra_hosts:
- myip:${HOST}
```

`docker-compose config` then shows

```
  extra_hosts:
      myip: test.example.com
```

To do this I followed the documentation from [Docker-compose environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) the section about `.env` file

UPDATE

According to the Docker documentation,

> Note: If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in
>   environment files will not be automatically visible during the build.
>   Use the args sub-option of build to define build-time environment
>   variables.

It basically means if you place your variables in `.env` file, you can use them for substitution in `docker-compose.yml`, but if you use `env_file` option for the particular container, you can only see the variables inside the Docker container, not during the build. It is also logical, `env_file` replaces `docker run --env-file=FILE ...` and nothing else.

So, you can only place your values into `.env`. Alternatively, as William described, you can use host's environment variables.

Comment: Which version of docker and docker compose are you using?

Comment: Interestingly, if I use env_file option, like in your example, this solution stops replacing. Investigating. It looks like `env_file` is not meant to provide replacements, only set env variables in container. Docker 1.12.0-a.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Try the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    container_name: myApplication
    env_file:
      - application.env
    build: ./myApplication/
    entrypoint: ./docker/api-startup.sh
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - redis    
    extra_hosts:
      - "myip:${SERVER_IP}"
```

Ensure curly bracers and that the environment variable exists on the host os.

Comment: Have you tried to export your server IP ? :  export SERVER_IP=10.10.9.134

Comment: Yes - sorry I was under the assumption SERVER_IP was also defined on the machine running docker compose