# Dockerfile pass environments on docker compose build

Tags: docker, arguments, environment-variables, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have written a `Dockerfile` which uses two arguments:

```
FROM jessie
MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
#Build Arguments
ARG REP_USER
ARG REP_PASS
# Build
RUN echo 'REP_USER:'$REP_USER', REP_PASS:'$REP_PASS
```

I wrote a `docker-compose.yml` for build:

```
version: "2"
services:
  ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        REP_USER: $REP_USER
        REP_PASS: $REP_PASS
```

I don't want to define these arguments directly in the compose file, so I tried to send them during docker compose build:

```
REP_USER=myusername REP_PASS=mypassword docker-compose build
```

Which didn't work. I changed my `Dockerfile` to use these arguments as environment variables; so I removed `ARG` lines:

```
FROM jessie
MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
# Build
RUN echo 'REP_USER:'$REP_USER', REP_PASS:'$REP_PASS
```

And `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"
  services:
    ui:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

And ran `REP_USER=myusername REP_PASS=mypassword docker-compose build`; still no result.

I also tried to save these information into an `env` file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - myenv.env
```

But it seems `env` files doesn't affect at build time; they are just take part into run time.

**EDIT 1:**

Docker version is `1.12.6` which doesn't support passing arguments with `--build-arg`.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried using `.env` file as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file):

```
cat .env 
REP_USER=myusername
REP_PASS=mypassword
```

I then called `docker-compose config` which returned:

```
networks: {}
services:
  ui:
    build:
      args:
        REP_PASS: mypassword
        REP_USER: myusername
      context: /home/zeinab/Workspace/ZiZi-Docker/Test/test-exec-1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
version: '2.0'
volumes: {}
```

Which means this resolved my issue.

**EDIT 3:**

I also tried third section of [docker-compose arg documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args) in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - REP_USER
        - REP_PASS
```

And executed:

```
export REP_USER=myusername;export REP_PASS=mypassword;sudo docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Still not getting what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I mentioned it in the question too. I first tried it with fail, then I found out that I had a typo naming `.env` file; it was `.evn`.

I tried using `.env` file as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file):

```
cat .env 
REP_USER=myusername
REP_PASS=mypassword
```

I then called `docker-compose config` which returned:

```
networks: {}
services:
  ui:
    build:
      args:
        REP_PASS: mypassword
        REP_USER: myusername
      context: /home/zeinab/Workspace/ZiZi-Docker/Test/test-exec-1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
version: '2.0'
volumes: {}
```

Which means this resolved my issue. I should mention that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414373/docker-compose-using-environment-variables-to-set-extra-host?answertab=active#tab-top) was really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can set build arguments with docker compose as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/):

```
docker-compose build [--build-arg key=val...]
docker-compose build --build-arg REP_USER=myusername --build-arg REP_PASS=mypassword
```

Btw, AFAIK build arguments are a compromise between usability and deterministic building. Docker aims to build in a deterministic fashion. That is, wherever you execute the build the produced image should be the same. Therefore, it appears logical that the client ignores the environment (variables) it is executed in.

Comment: my docker version is `1.12.6` which doesn't support that.

Comment: To bad. Updating is no option? In a "normal" Linux you can just put a recent version of `docker-compose` into `$HOME/bin` and it should be executed instead of the system default.

Comment: I'll check if updating is possible; not all work approaches are in my control at the office.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with "normal". Some corporate security measures might forbid it. If `$HOME/bin` is in the output of ` echo "$PATH"` it should work. (In principle)

Comment: And how should the docker-compose file look when doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for variable substitution in a docker-compose file is $`{VARNAME}`.
Try with this one:

```
version: "2"
  services:
    ui:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        REP_USER: ${REP_USER}
        REP_PASS: ${REP_PASS}
```