# docker-compose use environment variables from .env file

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment

I have some environment variables which I want to use in both `docker-compose` configurations and `Dockerfile`. I have an environment file named `.env` in order to make use of them in `docker-compose` file (a solution that I used for [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933083/dockerfile-pass-environments-on-docker-compose-build?answertab=active#tab-top)); but these environment variables are not reachable in node's `Dockerfile`. Consider `JMX_PORT`, `WS_PORT` and `IP` as variables which are defined in my `.env` file; I put an `echo` for each of them in my `Dockerfile` to check if they are passed to it or not.

I tried to put `.env` in the `env_file` section of the node:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mynode:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mynode
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${JMX_PORT}:${JMX_PORT}"
      - "${WS_PORT}:${WS_PORT}"
```

I also tried:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mynode:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mynode
    environment:
      - IP=${IP}
      - JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT}
      - WS_PORT=${WS_PORT}
    ports:
      - "${JMX_PORT}:${JMX_PORT}"
      - "${WS_PORT}:${WS_PORT}"
```

And with a little change:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mynode:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mynode
    environment:
      - IP
      - JMX_PORT
      - WS_PORT
    ports:
      - "${JMX_PORT}:${JMX_PORT}"
      - "${WS_PORT}:${WS_PORT}"
```

None of the above approaches worked.

I don't want to redefine them in another file. Is there any solution for that?

**EDIT 1:**

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mybaseimage
MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
RUN echo ${IP}
RUN echo ${JMX_PORT}
RUN echo ${WS_PORT}
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is the output of `docker-compose config` command which implies the `docker-compose` has access to the environment variables as expected:

```
services:
  mynode:
    build:
      context: /home/zeinab/Workspace/ZiZi-Docker/Test/test-1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-WRCore
    environment:
      IP: 171.80.80.80
      JMX_PORT: '1998'
      WS_PORT: '9000'
    ports:
    - 1998:1998
    - 9000:9000
version: '2.0'
volumes: {}
```

And this is the output of `docker-compose build --no-cache` command which implies the `Dockerfile` does not have access to the environment variables as expected:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
Building mynode
Step 1 : FROM mybaseimage
 ---> 875978d91e2e
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
 ---> Running in 250eac87d078
 ---> 0e7bd6a18c80
Removing intermediate container 250eac87d078
Step 3 : RUN echo ${IP}
 ---> Running in 4ee6dbf74b2a

 ---> fd2bff1de6b6
Removing intermediate container 4ee6dbf74b2a
Step 4 : RUN echo ${JMX_PORT}
 ---> Running in 01245df43926

 ---> 68b7e90b1c01
Removing intermediate container 01245df43926
Step 5 : RUN echo ${WS_PORT}
 ---> Running in d27db926ecac

 ---> a8c3d0cbade8
Removing intermediate container d27db926ecac
Successfully built a8c3d0cbade8
```

Comment: Post your Dockerfile also

Comment: @TarunLalwani, I have edited my question. Please review one more time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what you are doing is wrong. Reason being there is environment variable to be passed to Dockerfile while building. So there are two possible solutions

**Use Builder Arguments**

```
FROM mybaseimage
MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
ARG IP
ARG JMX_PORT
ARG WS_PORT
RUN echo ${IP}
RUN echo ${JMX_PORT}
RUN echo ${WS_PORT}
```

And then pass these build arguments using compose

```
version: "2"
services:
  mynode:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mynode
      args:
        - IP=${IP}
        - JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT}
        - WS_PORT=${WS_PORT}
    environment_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${JMX_PORT}:${JMX_PORT}"
      - "${WS_PORT}:${WS_PORT}"
```

Also you can load environment variables using `environment_file`. now this is only available when the container is started and they don't apply to your compose file or to your build file.

Also adding the build arguments will only make them available during the build and not during the container start. If you need to do that you need to define the variable twice

```
FROM mybaseimage
MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
ARG IP
ARG JMX_PORT
ARG WS_PORT
ENV IP=${IP} JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT} WS_PORT=${WS_PORT}
RUN env
```

**Copying the environment file**

**.env**

```
export NAME=TARUN
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
COPY .env /tmp/.env
RUN cat /tmp/.env > /etc/profile.d/tarun.sh && chmod +x /etc/profile.d/tarun.sh
SHELL ["sh","-lc"]
RUN env
```

In the `RUN cat /tmp/.env > /etc/profile.d/tarun.sh && chmod +x /etc/profile.d/tarun.sh` we create profile file which should be loaded when a shell is executed with profile.

In `SHELL ["sh","-lc"]` we change default shell from `sh -c` to `sh -l` so it can load our profile also.

Output of the last step is

```
Step 5/5 : RUN env
 ---> Running in 329ec287a5a6
HOSTNAME=e1ede117fb1e
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PAGER=less
PS1=\h:\w\$
NAME=TARUN
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
CHARSET=UTF-8
 ---> 6ab95f46e940
```

As you can see the environment variable is there.

> Note: This `.env` format cannot be loaded in `docker-compose` as we have an export statement which is a bash command

Comment: Thank you. I prefered to use the first approach and it solved teh issue.